# controlling the level of verbosity in Hive

Tags: hive

I run hive from command line that way:

```
hive -e "select * from table;"
```

and it gives me all the details and stage of my query.
If I do:

```
hive -S -e "select * from table;"
```

It doesn't give any detail.

What I would like to have is just to be shown the numbers of mappers and reducers for each step of map reduce, as well as the number of map reduce steps, but I don't want to see all the informations like:

```
2013-01-02 12:46:28,756 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 287.99 sec
```

So, is it possible to have a more granular control of the verbosity with Hive? Thanks!

Comment: Me too. I'm ending up with megs of log files filled just with lines like the one above, one per second.

Answer (score 1):

My "solution" to [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849289/how-do-i-limit-log-verbosity-of-hive) is

```
hive ... 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -v -e ' map = .*,  reduce = ' | tee log
```

This sucks (and might kill more than necessary), but this is the best I have been able to come up with so far.

EDIT: please watch and vote for [The logging (progress reporting) is too verbose](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6314)

Comment: Oooh, clever! I will try this when I go back to work. I am sure there are some tricks with the grep function to know only when it finished the first 10%, 20%, etc.