# How do I limit log verbosity of hive?

Tags: logging, hive

Hive produces a lot of log output like this:

```
2013-12-30 18:22:56,748 Stage-1 map = 94%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37473.86 sec
2013-12-30 18:22:57,795 Stage-1 map = 94%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37473.86 sec
2013-12-30 18:22:58,848 Stage-1 map = 94%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37710.8 sec
2013-12-30 18:22:59,893 Stage-1 map = 95%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37832.55 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:00,940 Stage-1 map = 95%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37949.67 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:01,987 Stage-1 map = 95%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37957.87 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:03,035 Stage-1 map = 95%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37957.87 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:04,075 Stage-1 map = 95%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37957.87 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:05,121 Stage-1 map = 95%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38025.0 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:06,171 Stage-1 map = 95%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38025.0 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:07,248 Stage-1 map = 96%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38060.66 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:08,305 Stage-1 map = 96%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38147.0 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:09,364 Stage-1 map = 96%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38181.2 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:10,408 Stage-1 map = 96%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38181.2 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:11,451 Stage-1 map = 96%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38192.39 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:12,502 Stage-1 map = 96%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38197.42 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:13,554 Stage-1 map = 96%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38234.51 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:14,606 Stage-1 map = 97%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38234.51 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:15,655 Stage-1 map = 97%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38268.89 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:16,706 Stage-1 map = 97%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38318.93 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:17,753 Stage-1 map = 97%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38350.56 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:18,809 Stage-1 map = 97%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38373.64 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:19,856 Stage-1 map = 97%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38400.22 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:20,909 Stage-1 map = 98%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38451.93 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:21,951 Stage-1 map = 98%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38600.23 sec
2013-12-30 18:23:23,001 Stage-1 map = 98%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38630.01 sec
```

This is nice, but far too verbose.

It it possible to limit the log output to, say, at most one line per minute?

EDIT: please watch and vote for the JIRA issue [The logging (progress reporting) is too verbose](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6314)

Comment: I have never seen any way to filter out the heartbeat messages either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [controlling the level of verbosity in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121543/controlling-the-level-of-verbosity-in-hive)